# MySQL compare all rows that share a given column value with rows that share another

Tags: mysql

Hello I am tying to compare the data contained in the `value` column for all rows containing `36` in the `customized_id` column and all rows containing `21`. I am interested in observing any variance between this data. Thank you!

```
| Customized_id  |  value  |
----------------------------
|     36         |  PASS   |
|     36         |  FAIL   |
|     36         |  PASS   |
|     21         |  PASS   |
|     21         |  PASS   |
|     21         |  FAIL   |
```

Using the following I was able to return somthing close to what i want, but the rows keep repeating on and on, which I am not sure how to fix. Once I have only the desired data returned, I would like to display only the rows where there is a difference in the "value" column data (PASS/FAIL) for each customized_id row.

```
SELECT b.customized_id, b.value, c.customized_id, c.value
FROM `redmine`.`custom_values` 
left join `redmine`.`custom_values` as b
      on b.customized_id = '36'
left join `redmine`.`custom_values` as c
      on c.customized_id = '21';



| Customized_id  |  value  | Customized_id   |  value |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|     36         |  PASS   |     21         |  FAIL   |
|     36         |  PASS   |     21         |  FAIL   |
|     36         |  PASS   |     21         |  PASS   |
|     36         |  PASS   |     21         |  PASS   |
|     36         |  PASS   |     21         |  PASS   |
|     36         |  PASS   |     21         |  PASS   |
```

Comment: Yeah, looks like you've got it just about right to me.

Comment: What do you want as results?

Comment: Unfortunately, neither smart nor psychic :-(

Comment: Gordon thank you for responding, from a table containing many values, I am able to isolate all the data for rows containing the desired values of the customized_id column, (36 and 21) as seen in my diagram. I would now like to compare it, so I would need to treat the data as two tables being compared to each other, one consisting of only customized_id=36 and one with customized_id=21. I need to see any variance for the PASS/FAIL data in the "value" column

Comment: How should rows from each group be correlated? Do you just want to know if each group has the same number of passes and fails?

Comment: Hi Barmar, I would just like to know if there is difference in the PASS and FAIL values for each row. So, for a given row, if customized_id:36 shows "PASS" but customized_id:21 shows "FAIL", as seen above, only this row should be shown. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT Customized_id, COUNT(DISTINCT value) values
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY Customized_id
```

This will tell you if all the values for a particular ID are the same or different.

Comment: Thank you for responding Barmar, I tried this but nothing is returned when I execute.

Answer (score 0):

is this what you are looking for?

```
SELECT a.customized_id, a.value
FROM `redmine`.`custom_values` as a
left join `redmine`.`custom_values` as b
      on b.customized_id = 24
left join `redmine`.`custom_values` as c
      on c.customized_id = 36
left join //something else
```

Comment: Thanks for answering Alex. This executes, but it returns only rows where customized_id = 2

Comment: I have modified the solution you gave me slightly to get a little closer to what I want. I updated my question to show the modifed code. Thank you for you help!